# Xamarin Android Layout Resources in library project not included in Application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android library project which is referenced by an Android application project.

The library project has layout files which need to be used by a library project component.  The Resource.designer.cs file seems to be generated properly.  The layouts are marked as Android Resources.   Yet at runtime the resources are not there.  Trying to access them just returns 0.

After reading all the SO questions on the topic, I am convinced this should work, but so far it doesn't.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the Android Class Library.
   [image]
2. Create a layout folder in this class library and create a layout in this folder.
   [image]
3. Add the code in your xamarin android app.

   ```
   var btn_Load = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_LoadLibraryLayout);
       btn_Load.Click += delegate
       {
           SetContentView(ClassLibrary1.Resource.Layout.library_layout);
       };
   ```

I create a button to open the layout in class library.

**Result:**

[image]

You could download from the ClassLibrary_layout folder of GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

**Updated:**

If you want to get the resource identifier, you need the package name of this class library. First, we could not get the package name in AndroidManifest.xml file or properties, because the class library does not have it.

You could get it from the steps below.

1. Create a activity in class library. And get the package name with the code.

   ```
   var PackageNname = Application.Context.PackageName;
   ```
2. You could also get the resource identifier in this activity.

   ```
   var resId2 = Resources.GetIdentifier("library_layout", "layout", PackageNname);
   ```

**Result:**

[image]

The paskage name is same to the app1 I provided. 
Package Name: `com.companyname.app1`

You could also use the code directly in app1 activity.

```
   int resId2 = Resources.GetIdentifier("library_layout", "layout", "com.companyname.app1");
```

Comment: I think this is why I can't find information on this problem.  In theory, it should "just work".  However, when I try to access--from the app project--the equivalent of `ClassLibrary1.Resource.Layout.library_layout` at run time, it is `0`.   Also, if I try to access the resource from within the library project code the resource is `0`.  I have deleted the `Resource.Designer.cs` and it regenerates fine.  It's strange.

Comment: Maybe we can track this down.  I opened your sample and added the following line to the `MainActivity.cs`  `int resId = Resources.GetIdentifier("library_layout", "layout", "ClassLibrary1");` and in fact, it returns `0`.  Is the library reference not correct?

Comment: You get the '0' due to the wrong package name. I have update my reply, please check it.

Comment: I guess this answer is correct, but the trouble with this is that the library project code has to know what app it is in, so that the library code can access the resource.